# Enabling fullscreen option from cartodb.createVis

Tags: carto

Is there an option to enable the fullscreen toggle through the API?

Seems the docs haven't been updated to reflect this update: http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-3-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We forgot to add the doc, the right way to add it is:

```
createVis('el', 'viz.json', {
  fullscreen: true // this adds the button
})
```

This was just added to the documentation https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/commit/3bb50cf742695ddfddab89caa953c5bd48bf1fd0

Comment: right - note that tiles_loader must be set to true (this is the default setting)

Comment: the icon doesn't quite fall into the div, suggest updating cartodb.css line 837 as .cartodb-fullscreen a { width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #ffffff url('http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/img/fullscreen.png') no-repeat 2px -2px; }

Comment: @danpaz: I can't reproduce the issue. Which browser are you using? Could you show us a screenshot?

Comment: @javisantana looked a little closer and it is a conflict with bootstrap